# Box around zigzag line tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a zigzag-line, which I can get in TikZ by using

`\draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag}] (nodea) to [in 315, out = 320] (nodeb);`.

But I want this zigzag-Line to look more like this,
[image]

with the red box around it.

Comment: Since we don't have your zigzag line and it isn't clear what it would mean to box bits of it, it is very hard to say. Please provide a complete, minimal example we can copy-paste and compile to get your line, together with a more specific description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cfr, Thanks for the advice, I have edited my question.

Comment: We still cannot compile your example. It is just a fragment of code. `nodea` and `nodeb` are unknown, there's no document class, the required packages/libraries aren't loaded etc. And there's a typo in the line we do have.

Comment: The line you've specified seems to be curved, but the line you show appears straight.

Comment: @ Down-voters: Please do not downvote below -1. A score of -1 is quite sufficient to show a question needs improvement. Also, please do not downvote without leaving a comment explaining how to improve the question.

Answer (score 8):

Since I have no idea what the question is, this is distantly and coincidentally related at best. Still, maybe it will help somebody - possibly even the OP.

[image: zigzag variations]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw  (0,0) edge [decorate, decoration = {zigzag}] ++(5,5) rectangle ++(5,5) -| cycle;
  \draw  (5.5,0) edge [decorate, decoration = {zigzag}] ++(5,5) -| ++(2.5,5) -- ++(2.5,0);
  \begin{scope}
    \filldraw [clip] (11,0) rectangle ++(5,5);
    \filldraw [decorate, decoration = {zigzag}, white] (10,-1) -- ++(7,7)  |- cycle;
    \draw  (11,0) rectangle ++(5,5);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (16.5,0) rectangle ++(5,5);
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 100/\i, evaluate=\i as \k using (\i-1)/2] in {1,...,100} \draw [line width=.5mm, black!\j, decorate, decoration=zigzag] ([yshift=-\k mm, xshift=\k mm]16.5,0) -- ++(5,5);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

Given the added picture, something like this may be helpful:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [double distance=5.4pt, draw=red, postaction={decorate, draw=black, decoration=zigzag}] (0,0) -- (40pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: double 'n zigzag]

5pt is twice the default amplitude for the decoration and 5.4pt adds the default line width.